# fastest bidirectional java prolog implementation

Tags: java, prolog, ffi

I am trying to use a a java-prolog layer on top of my current agent-based simulation. I am running Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Netbeans 6.9 and tried to use JPL from swi-prolog however I haven't managed to run a test successfully due to problems with the libraries and their paths. I need a very fast implementation and I was wondering if anyone has any benchmarks or personal experience with bidirectional java-prolog interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

In 2007 I ran the classic Prolog benchmarks (programs such as `queens`, `tak`, `qsort`, `nrev` and so on) against four Prolog implementations written in Java: [tuProlog](http://tuprolog.sourceforge.net), [JIProlog](http://www.ugosweb.com/jiprolog), [JLog](http://jlogic.sourceforge.net) and [JavaLog](http://www.exa.unicen.edu.ar/isistan/javalog.html). The overall fastest implementation was JLog. All details can be found in [an article accepted at SAC 2008](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1363739).

I'd suggest you have a look also at [jTrolog](https://jtrolog.dev.java.net/), which was officially born after I measured the performance of the other Java-based Prolog engines. Perhaps [PrologCafe](http://kaminari.istc.kobe-u.ac.jp/PrologCafe/) may be of some interest, too.

Note, however, that I am not informed about the maintenance state of any of them. Choose carefully if you need some kind of support by their respective authors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to exchange messages efficiently between a java process and a prolog process?

I might recommend Google's Protocol Buffers, which provides a language-neutral and efficient means for exchanging messages between different systems...

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/protobufs.html

Comment: I am mainly looking into building a reasoning engine for agents in my simulations. I am not sure how the protocol buffers will help me with that. What I want is to run the reasoning code in Prolog and get the results back in java in order to perform certain actions. In a similar manner I would like to execute java methods from Prolog. The key is to have a portable engine per agent that is very efficient.